# Problema en funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buenas tardes GRan comunidad. tengo un problema en una funcion que anda al 90%. El problema esta en el BeforeSend del codigo, cuando yo elimino un item del carrito, se activa un spinner, pero se activa en todos los elementos, y yo quiero que solamente se active en el elemento que quiero eliminar. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
$(document).on("click", ".removecartitem", function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var rurl = $t.attr("data-remove-url");
    var delrowid = $t.attr("datarowid");
    var qty = $t.attr("dataitemqty");
    var spn = $(".remover-spinner") ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: rurl,
        beforeSend: function(data){

            spn.fadeIn(100)


   },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.'+delrowid).fadeOut(200, function(){
                spn.fadeOut(100)
                $('.'+delrowid).remove(); carttotalamount();

            }); 
        }
    });
});



<p class="remove_link">
                            <!-- a rel="nofollow" class="removecartitem" href="javascript:;" datarowid="removerowitem{$products.id}" dataitemqty="{$products.quantity}" data-remove-url="{$products.remove_from_cart_url}"> -->

                    <a rel="nofollow" class="removecartitem" href="javascript:;" datarowid="removerowitem{$products.id}" dataitemqty="{$products.quantity}" data-remove-url="{$products.remove_from_cart_url}">
                            <span class="remove-cartsection"><i class="material-icons" id="remover-product">delete_forever</i></span>
                            <span class="remover-spinner"></span>
                    </a>
</p>
```

Muchas gracias por su extrema colaboración !

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El selector que tienes escoge todos los spinners.  Debes cambiarlo asi:

```
$(document).on("click", ".removecartitem", function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var rurl = $t.attr("data-remove-url");
    var delrowid = $t.attr("datarowid");
    var qty = $t.attr("dataitemqty");
    var spn = $(this).find(".remover-spinner") ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: rurl,
        beforeSend: function(data){

            spn.fadeIn(100)    

   },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.'+delrowid).fadeOut(200, function(){
                spn.fadeOut(100)
                $('.'+delrowid).remove(); carttotalamount();

            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Excelente, perdon por quitarte tu valioso tiempo! Verdaderamente funciona con exito, muchas gracias alan!